# Equip a theorem with margin bar

Tags: theorems, marginpar, patching, changebar

Using PDFLaTeX, I am trying to equip theorem-like environments with a colored bar in the outer margin of the document. These theorems are already using the (nice) `thmbox` formatting. After trying the `framed` and then `mdframe` packages, I have found that the best solution to really use the document margin was the `changebar` package.

I tried to patch the commands defined for each theorem by using `etoolbox` to no avail, and after a bit of searching the documentation to `regexpatch` tells (in a rather complicated way --- for me) that this may be because of the optional first argument.

However, using `regexpatch`'s `xapptocmd` in place of `\apptocmd` does not help. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage[pdftex,color,outerbars]{changebar}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\xapptocmd{\definition}{\begin{changebar}}{}{\message{failure}}
\xpretocmd{\enddefinition}{\end{changebar}}{}{\message{failure}}


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Square]
Given any number $a$, the square of $a$ is the number
\[a^2=a\times a.\]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this code gives me 5 errors, mainly about badly closed environments (`\begin{definition}` ended by `\end{changebar}` is the first error).

If I comment out the `\usepackage{thmbox}`, the compilation goes on but no changebar appears in the margin.

If I comment out the patching lines in the preamble and write in the document

```
\begin{definition}[Square]\begin{changebar}
Given any number $a$, the square of $a$ is the number
\[a^2=a\times a.\]
\end{changebar}\end{definition}
```

Then I get what I want... But I can't do that in every single definition I have in my real document.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**note that three (!) compilation steps seem to be required**

*I have the changebar environment enclosing the definition one because I did not read closely enough the OP, use:*

```
\newenvironment{cdefinition}[1][]
    {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\begin{definition}\else
                      \begin{definition}[#1]\fi\begin{changebar}}
    {\end{changebar}\end{definition}}
```

*for `changebar` inside rather than outside.*

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage[pdftex,color,outerbars]{changebar}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newenvironment{cdefinition}[1][]
    {\begin{changebar}\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\begin{definition}\else
                      \begin{definition}[#1]\fi}
    {\end{definition}\end{changebar}}


\begin{document}

  \begin{cdefinition}[Square]
    Given any number $a$, the square of $a$ is the number
    \[a^2=a\times a\;.\]
  \end{cdefinition}

another one:

  \begin{cdefinition}[Cube]
    Given any number $a$, the cube of $a$ is the number
    \[a^3=a\times (a\times a) = (a\times a)\times a\;.\]
  \end{cdefinition}

and another one:

  \begin{cdefinition}
    Given any non-zero number $a$, the inverse of $a$ is the number
    \[a^{-1}=\frac1a\;.\]
  \end{cdefinition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

alternative:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your alternative with the changebar "inside" the theorem is what I want, I would never have thought of using things as detokenize to test the argument. I guess this should go into the patching of the regexpatch, and it's still frustrating not understanding why it won't work although it claims it does.

Is there a way to additionally keep the original theorem name ? I don't want to define a new environment name, I just want to be able to recompile my existing document with just an additional class option.

Thanks again !

Comment: it surely is possible to keep the former environment name, e.g. just do `\newtheorem{definitionbis}{Definition}` and then use `definition` rather than `\cdefinition` in my code above, with naturally `definitionbis` rather than `defintiion` inside. As per patching why bother ? there can not be a general solution, any solution be it `regexpatch` or anything else puts constraints and what will work with it. One can always examine the source code of the things one wants to patch and act accordingly. IIn this case I didn't even bother check what `thmbox` does.

Comment: as per the use of `\detokenize` for the safe emptiness check, as far as I know it was first promoted by @HeikoOberdiek. White space will make the conditional choose the false branch.

Comment: _puts constraints and what will work with it._, I meant naturally puts constraints on what will work with it.

Comment: I get your point about environment names and perhaps I should have been clearer in my initial question. Thing is that my environments definition, theorem and numerous such others already exist and are being used. I just want that, by adding a macro (which will end up in my custom package) such environments automatically get the colorbar in the margin. My ultimate goal is to write a command that enables me to say \givecolorbar{definition}{red} to automatically add a red bar to all definitions.

Comment: This is why I talked about patching in the first place, as the regexpatch author claims to deal with commands having an optional first parameter like theorem-like environments. Well that's what I understood from it.

Now considering your solution, would it be possible to "move" the unpatched theorem environment to a new name, define the new environment with the old name and call the renamed old environment within the new definition ? If so that would answer my specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution with the `framed` option of `ntheorem`, based on `framed`. It can break across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremprework{%
\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{-9pt}\vrule width 3pt \hspace{6pt}}
}%
\newframedtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremprework{%
\def\FrameCommand{{\color{IndianRed3}{\hspace{-8pt}\vrule width 2pt \hspace{6pt}}}}
}
\newframedtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\def\FrameHeightAdjust{20pt}
\mbox{}
\vskip 15cm
\begin{definition}[Square]
  Given any number $a$, the square of $a$ is the number
  \[a^2=a\times a.\]
\end{definition}
\begin{thm}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but unless I'm mistaken this left bar does not go into the document margin, it rather pushes the theorem content to the right. The framed documentation claims that it produces an "ordinary frame box (\fbox) with edge at margin", not _into_ the margin.

Moreover, I really want to keep the thmbox layout.

Comment: You didn't mention that. I can manage to put it in the margin. B.t.w., as far as I know, the `thmbox`es do not break across pages?

Comment: @Frédéric Delacroix: Please see my updated answer. I've added the `geometry` package with `showframe` option. You have full control on the distance between the leftbar and the left margin.